# Force Parallel.ForEach make one thread per item in collection

Tags: c#, .net, parallel-processing

Here is code sample I have used:

```
        Stopwatch s = new Stopwatch();
        s.Start();

        ParallelOptions po = new ParallelOptions();
        // hosts contain 23 items
        po.MaxDegreeOfParallelism = hosts.Count();

        Parallel.ForEach(hosts, po, p =>
            {
                using (TcpClient tcpClient = new TcpClient())
                {
                    IAsyncResult result = tcpClient.BeginConnect(p.Value, 80, null, null);
                    WaitHandle timeoutHandler = result.AsyncWaitHandle;
                    try
                    {
                        if (!result.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne(1000, false))
                        {
                            tasks.TryAdd(p.Key, new TaskCompleteResult { result = false, exc = new Exception("By timeout") });
                            tcpClient.Close();
                        }
                        else
                        {                             
                            tasks.TryAdd(p.Key, new TaskCompleteResult { result = true, exc = null });
                        }

                        tcpClient.EndConnect(result);
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        tasks.TryAdd(p.Key, new TaskCompleteResult { result = false, exc = ex });
                    }
                    finally
                    {
                        timeoutHandler.Close();
                    }
                }
            });

        s.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine(s.Elapsed.TotalSeconds);
```

So, as I thought it will give me 1 (or maybe 2, if we take in attention some overhead work) seconds, but it take 4 seconds. Does Parallel.ForEach takes threads from some prepared before thread pool or creates the new ones? How can I achieve 1-2 seconds work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Threads are only really useful if your constraint is CPU. All you are doing is having lots of threads *individually* doing nothing, and doing nothing in parallel.

I would approach this a very different way. What you are doing now is:

- create lots of threads
- each of which creates a wait handle and then blocks for up to 1 second

I would turn it around:

- create lots of wait handles
- then start blocking for **what remains of** one second

At the simplest (pseudo-code):

```
WaitHandle[] handles = ... start all the async tasks...
Thread.Sleep(1000);
foreach(handle)
    handle.WaitOne(0) ... log result
```

But possibly something involving:

```
WaitHandle[] handles = ... start all the async tasks...
System.Threading.WaitHandle.WaitAll(handles, 1000);
foreach(handle ...)
    handle.WaitOne(0) ... log result
```

Also: you might consider replacing `new Exception("By timeout")` with `new TimeoutException()`.

Comment: Nice trick! But how can I determine that exception has occured (here is place about I'm talking `catch (Exception ex) { tasks.TryAdd(p.Key, new TaskCompleteResult { result = false, exc = ex }); }`)? Or there is nothing about should I care?

Comment: @kseen you should still be able to WaitOne on it to see if it finished; and if so, use EndConnect